# SYSVOL not replicating between DC's

Tags: domain, dfs

I've been struggling all day trying to fix this issue..
I recently added a secondary DC, everything worked for 2 weeks or so.
Now, the last 2 days I noticed it doesn't replicate the policies..
That's the error I get when I run dcdiag:

> Starting test: DFSREvent There are warning or error events within the
>   last 24 hours after the SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL 
>   replication problems may cause Group Policy problems.

Now, when I browse to \domain1\sysvol\domain1\Policies\ - I see 57 policies ( the correct number ).
when I go browse to \domain2\sysvol\domain2\Policies\ - I see 30 policies only..
so I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing?
I'm using DFS.
the DFS service is working and I also tried to restart the service..

Event viewer:

All I can find is event id 5014

> The DFS Replication service is stopping communication with   partner
>   ''''' for replication group Domain System Volume due   to an error.
>   The service will retry the connection periodically.

And right after that I get 'success' events.

Comment: Turn on debug logging and check log file under %windir%\debug
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/03/23/understanding-dfsr-debug-logging-part-1-logging-levels-log-format-guids/

Comment: Have you gone through basic domain troubleshooting and made sure DNS is all correct, Sites are set up correctly, etc? You can run `dcdiag` and `repadmin` on relevant DCs to gain more insight.